# Redirect 'arqade.stackexchange.com'

Tags: feature-request, domain-name

I'm surprisingly often tripped up by the fact that `gaming.stackexchange.com` is named `Arqade`; I sometimes mistakenly start writing `arqade.stackexchange.com`.

My browser usually corrects me, but I'm assuming I'm not the only one who makes this mistake. Would it be a good idea to redirect the `arqade` subdomain to `gaming`?

Comment: Only the "index" page would need to be redirected, as I don't see it likely that people will incorrectly type out or link to an entire url.

Comment: arqade.com already redirects, and you don't even need to type out .stackexchange in the middle of it.

Comment: +1. @3ventic It's about helping those of us who manage to remember how to spell "arqade" and then assume we can append ".stackexchange.com."